# How can I: Convert Physical to VM, the machine it's running on

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, vmware-converter

I have virtualized laptops before, when someone gets a new one and doesn't want to quite let go of their old laptop for fear of losing something.

This was using VMWare Workstation 7.X.  In 8.0 when I go to "Convert a Physical Machine to a Virtual Machine", it asks for an IP address and doesn't give the option to virtualize the machine it's running on.  How to I get VMWare to virtualize it's current system?

I tried typing in Localhost, and 127.0.0.1 but that didn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the VMWare vCenter Converter Standalone Client
2. Choose to connect to a local server
3. Click convert machine
4. Choose a "powered-on machine"
5. Click "this local machine"
6. Select destination type as VMWare Workstation virtual machine
7. Select a location (pick a different drive)
8. Click next then check that you have the proper "hardware" selected for the VM you want to build.